# Does the Box Content API have a way to turn off email notifications on a folder?

Tags: box-api

We want to prevent notifications from a folder that is used for an application without modifying our user's notifications settings.  I notice Box has this functionality :

This is a screenshot from the Email tab in a folder's properies:

[image]

I don't see any way of selecting the "Disable notifications for this folder" via the /folder endpoints ...

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a way to update many of the folder security properties via the API right now, including disable notifications, hide collaborators, or only allow company domain collaboration invites.